# Searching for a substring in a list of a billion unique strings

Tags: scalability, database-performance

I have a list of about a billion unique strings, most a few dozen characters in length. I'd like to find all strings that contain or match a search string, ideally in less than 100-200ms, and on as little hardware as possible (I assume I'll need a good amount of RAM). What is the best way to go about storing and retrieving this?

- From what I've read, MySQL's `LIKE '%search%'` doesn't use an index, but `LIKE '%search'` AND `LIKE 'search%'` both do. This is acceptable as a last resort, but not ideal as I'd like to find the search string anywhere within the target strings.
- Using a key-value store like Redis would require every possible substring combination to be stored and, I assume, a lot of RAM.
- The list of strings is roughly a dozen GB large. Is a full-text search server like Lucene viable, or even ideal, for this instead of having billions of rows/documents/records? It'd sure save on parsing.

Comment: And since this question doesn't really have a clear cut answer, should this be converted to a community wiki?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using one of many MapReduce frameworks to solve your problem? The essence of MapReduce is you divide and conquer so you are solving a very simple problem (say, does just one of your billion unique strings contain your search term) a billion times, then you combine a billion answers into a single answer.  And instead of having just one machine with a lot of RAM to solve your problem, you can ask many lesser equipped machines to solve your problem together. Check it out.  It might be what you are looking for.